# Django: writing test for multiple database site

Tags: python, django

I have 2 sites: A and B. A relies on some tables from B so it has an entry in its `DATABASES` settings pointing to B together with some entries under its `DATABASE_ROUTERS` settings to route certain model access to B's database.

Now I'm trying to write a test on A but just running `manage.py test` immediately fails because some of A's models relies on some models covered by the tables coming from B, and B's complete database tables hasn't been created yet.

So my question is, how do I tweak my `TEST_RUNNER` to first run `syncdb` on B against B's test db so then when I run `manage.py test` on A it can find the tables from B that it relies on?

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to have all tables in the same database for testing?

Comment: hmm.. but the entries in DATABASES settings have two different name for A and B, using only one db leaves A there and the DB routers expects B to be present there.

Comment: You could use the same settings for A and B as well... and [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#overriding-settings) `DATABASE`/`DATABASE_ROUTERS` settings for tests...

Comment: ah right, actually just the `DATABASES` settings needs to be overridden, the routers should work just fine as long as there's a B entry even though we changed it to use the same settings as A. Will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your setup you probably need to have a look at your [`allow_syncdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_syncdb) method on your router class!

Comment: Yep, I actually have those method and its is hard-wire to only sync if db == B, so its important to override B's entry in mt DATABASES settings.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not an option for your tests to have all the data in one database (eg. having a different router setting for the tests) you should look into creating your own [`TEST_RUNNER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#test-runner). Maybe [this](http://googletorp.com/blog/how-run-sql-django-test-database-syncdb) will point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I finally get the tests running, here's what I did:

- disabled `DATABASE_ROUTERS` settings when running tests
- maintain B alias in `DATABASES` settings but the name is the same as A
- append B's `INSTALLED_APPS` that aren't present to A's `INSTALLED_APPS`